# Requesting JSON data in python for web-scraping

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, url, python-requests

I use the code below to fetch the JSON data for some of the stocks (e.g.  https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/tsla/forecast  ):

```
import json
import requests
url = " https://tr-frontend-cdn.azureedge.net/bff/prod/stock/tsla/payload.json?ver=1678406987078"
req = requests.get(url)
data = req.json()
```

But the website also has the data for ETF's (for example,
https://www.tipranks.com/etf/xlb/forecast  )
But I don'y know that url to use in this case (I tried  https://tr-frontend-cdn.azureedge.net/bff/prod/etf/xlp/payload.json?ver=1678406987078   but this does not work).

Can someone help me identify what url should I put to properly get the JSON data?

Comment: The URL you showed in the code is returning JSON data, try using res.json() to parse the data as JSON

Answer (score 1):

What I do in such case is:

- Open my browser inspector
- Go to the network tab
- Filter requests by XHR
- Navigate the request list and check the response for each of them, until I find what I want

In your case, you did not precise what data you were looking for, but I suspect this could be the endpoint you were looking for: https://www.tipranks.com/etf/xlb/payload.json

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `User-Agent` header:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.tipranks.com/etf/xlb/payload.json'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0'
}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "_meta": {
        "time": 1679207354777
    },
    "forecast": {
        "isHaveData": true,
        "highestUpside": [
            {
                "type": "stock",
                "isTraded": true,
                "ticker": "ALB",
                "name": "Albemarle Corporation",
                "fullName": "Albemarle Corporation",
                "gain": {
                    "yearly": 0.05837
                },
                "sector": "basicmaterials",
                "smartScore": {
                    "value": 7
                },
                "tradeOn": "us",
                "marketCap": 24434606485,
                "price": null,
                "analystRatings": {
                    "consensus": {
                        "id": "moderateBuy",
                        "buy": 9,
                        "sell": 2,
                        "hold": 7,
                        "total": 18,
                        "priceTarget": {
                            "value": 308.69
                        }
                    },
                    "bestConsensus": null
                },
                "holdingData": {
                    "shares": 726543,
                    "ratio": 0.029,
                    "value": 155923393.23,
                    "currency": "USD"
                }
            },

...and so on.
```